# How to autogenerate additional sequences with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
```

This annotation will create the following sequence in postgresql:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 0
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE hibernate_sequence
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

How can I annotate the `id` field in a way that hibernate autogenerates an additional sequence, and then this sequence is used to increment only rows in this specific table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need create a sequence and follow this way

/**
 * The persistent class for the TB_FINALIDADE_PORTARIA database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_FINALIDADE_PORTARIA")
public class FinalidadePortaria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="FINALIDADE_PORTARIA_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SQ_FINALIDADE_PORTARIA")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="FINALIDADE_PORTARIA_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="ID_FINALIDADE_PORTARIA")
    private Long id;
```